# Spring Boot Application does not create .jar file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring boot.application which creates a TCP server implemented using Netty. I have created the application and tested it and all works fine.

The problem is when I want to build a jar from the source, the jar is not created.TCP server starts and responds to client requests but jar is not created in target folder.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"some.package"})
public class OtpServiceApplication implements ApplicationRunner
{
    @Autowired
    TcpServer tcpServer;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception
    {
        tcpServer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(OtpServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**However, when I remove the TCP related code,jar is created successfully.**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"some.package"})
public class OtpServiceApplication 
{
//    @Autowired
//    TcpServer tcpServer;
//
//    @Override
//    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception
//    {
//        tcpServer.start();
//    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(OtpServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Therefore I guess it is not a problem with my POM file or code but it is a problem in this class. Can someone please point out how to resolve this?

This is my TcpServer class.

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelOption;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class TcpServer {

    @Autowired
    XmlProcessor xmlProcessor;

    @Autowired
    IdleSocketHandler idleSocketHandler;

    @Value("${request.timeout:5000}")
    String requestTimeout;

    @Value("${response.timeout:2000}")
    String responseTimeout;

    @Value("${message-listener.port}")
    String xmlListenerPort;

    @Value("${message-listener.ip}")
    String xmlListenerIp;

    private NioEventLoopGroup connectionAcceptorThreadGroup;
    private NioEventLoopGroup connectionProcessorThreadGroup;
    private ChannelFuture serverSocketFuture;

    @Async
    public void start() throws InterruptedException {

        log.info("Starting XML Listener on [{}:{}]", xmlListenerIp, xmlListenerPort);

        this.connectionAcceptorThreadGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        this.connectionProcessorThreadGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        final int resTimeout = Integer.valueOf(responseTimeout);

        final int reqTimeout = Math.min(Integer.valueOf(requestTimeout), (int) (resTimeout * 1.8));

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

            b.group(connectionAcceptorThreadGroup, connectionProcessorThreadGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("requestHandler", xmlProcessor);
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler",
                                    new IdleStateHandler(reqTimeout, resTimeout, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                            ch.pipeline().addLast("idleSocketHandler", idleSocketHandler);
                        }
                    })
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR,true)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

            serverSocketFuture = b.bind(xmlListenerIp, Integer.valueOf(xmlListenerPort)).sync();
            log.info("Server listening for transactions on {}:{}", xmlListenerIp, xmlListenerPort);
            serverSocketFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            connectionProcessorThreadGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            connectionAcceptorThreadGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not Autowire below class because before autowiring any class it should be the part of those class which follow stereotype concept so create another class with @Component, @Servive...etc as per your logic and then autowire within this class.

```
    @Autowired
    TcpServer tcpServer;
```

can  you try to impose this class somewhere else except main class and try to create a jar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Autowiring get the application context so that the bean is created like this

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = 
SpringApplication.run(OtpServiceApplication.class, args);

TcpSrever tcpServer = applicationContext.getBean(TcpServer.class);

tcpServer.run()
```